# Switch ALL Java executable binaries to point to another JDK|JRE version with a single command

Tags: linux, linux-mint, path, java

I know that I can use `update-alternatives` util to link specific executalbe to another alternative path.

I also know about `JAVA_HOME`, `JDK_HOME`, `JRE_HOME` etc... but I would prefer to manipulate default links in `/usr/bin/`.

That can be done separately for `java`, `javac`, `javap`, `jar` etc...
But is there a way to do that for all binaries (or a predefined set of binaries) at once with a single command better than a custom self-prepared script?

Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `update-java-alternatives` will do this for you:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
```

will list the available JREs and JDKs, and

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

will update *all* the relevant links to point to `java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64` (replace with the appropriate JRE or JDK in your case).